# Can I expand a macro inside a quote of another macro in Elixir?

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

Given the below code, the line `use Composite, user_opts: user_opts` ends up as `[{:user_opts, [line: 3, counter: {MockUserNode1, 2}], Automaton.Node}]` inside the **using**(opts) as opts. Is there any way to inject that code inside the outer macro?

```
defmacro __using__(user_opts) do
    a =
      if Enum.member?(Composite.types(), user_opts[:node_type]) do
        IO.inspect(user_opts)

        quote bind_quoted: [user_opts: user_opts] do
          use DynamicSupervisor
          use Composite, user_opts: user_opts
        end
      else
        quote do: use(Action)
      end
end
```

Comment: can you make your question more clear? show an example of what you expect to get at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question stated: it’s perfectly possible to call macros from inside other macros, the just inject the AST recursively in the end.

```rb
defmodule DeeplyUsed do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do
      opts
    end
  end
end

defmodule Used do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do
      use DeeplyUsed, opts: opts
    end
  end
end

defmodule Using do
  use Used, line: 3, counter: {MockUserNode1, 2}
end
```

That said, your issue is induced.

---

*Sidenote:* `[{:user_opts, _, Automaton.Node}]` looks indeed very suspicious there, that’s not how keyword lists are being quoted. Start with explicit unquoting *and* logging what comes to `user_opts` there.

```rb
defmacro __using__(user_opts) do
  IO.inspect(user_opts, label: "Outside")
  quote do
    IO.inspect(unquote(user_opts), label: "Inside")
    use Composite, user_opts: unquote(user_opts)
  end
end
```